# How can I see the expire date of a file in Tivoli Storage Manager?

Tags: backup, incremental-backup, tsm

If I understand correctly, when I do an incremental backup and a file has been removed from the client, the server marks it as inactive which makes it eligible for purging when the expire time has passed.

Using the `dsmc` client on a linux server I can see the list of inactive files, but no information is shown on how long they will be kept.

How can I know exactly when a specific inactive file will expire?
Also: where do I configure the expire time and how do I see which value it is currently set to?

Answer (score 0):

Expiration time for a specific file is defined in MGMT class to which it belongs when file was backed up. Here is detailed explanation how it works in TSM:
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224145

You can get information about each file on server using SQL Query in dsmadmc:

```
SELECT * FROM backups WHERE node_name='<nodename>' AND ll_name='<filename>'
```

More examples here:
http://thobias.org/tsm/sql/#toc155